# Is there 64-bit version pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

When i install pymongo using easy_install with 64-bit python, exception happens. But it works with 32-bit python. It seems only 32-bit python is supported.

So i want to know whether 64-bit pymongo exists?

Thanks.

--- more details ---

```
    running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pymongo.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pymongo.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pymongo.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pymongo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'pymongo'
writing manifest file 'pymongo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'bson._cbson' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\mongodb-mongo-python-driver-7269ec4\setup.py", line 184, in <module>
    "doc": doc})
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 76, in ru
n
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 96, in do
_egg_install
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 175, in
 run
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 161, in
 call_command
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 20, i
n run
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 112, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "F:\mongodb-mongo-python-driver-7269ec4\setup.py", line 108, in run
    build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 471, in build_exte
nsions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "F:\mongodb-mongo-python-driver-7269ec4\setup.py", line 118, in build_ext
ension
    build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 536, in build_exte
nsion
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 448, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 358, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 274, in query_vcvarsal
l
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

Comment: Did you run `vcvarsall.bat` first to initialize the environment?

Comment: Wow, it works. Run vcvarsall.bat first, then install pymongo. Thank you, Ignacio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run vcvarsall.bat first, then install pymongo.